# How to retrieve blob data images from database and assign a session to it?

Tags: php, sql, html

There is probably error in the syntax:

```
.base64_encode($_SESSION[$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE]])
```

This is supposed to retrieve a product's image from the database which is in blob format. The anchor links it to a `Productdetails.php` page, where each product's description is displayed.

I wanted to assign a session on retrieving the image from the database, so when users click on the product, they see the particular product's description.
Also, the images are stored in the column `PRODUCT_IMAGE`. Thanks.

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from products");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<div class = "product-image-wrapper">
    <a href = "Productdetails.php">
        <?php echo '<img src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($_SESSION[$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE']]).'" alt = "" width = "250px" height ="300px"/>'; ?>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to `$_SESSION[$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE]]` to `$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE']` and assign `$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE']` to session variable

```
<?php
 session_start();
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from products");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {   

 $_SESSION['image']=$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE'];
?>
<div class = "product-image-wrapper">
    <a href = "Productdetails.php">
        <?php echo '<img src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['PRODUCT_IMAGE']).'" alt = "" width = "250px" height ="300px"/>'; ?>
    </a>
```

Comment: thanks Arun.I am sure the session is assigned. However, in the Productsdetail.php  page I am using the same 
<?php echo '<img src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['PRODUCT_IMAGE']).'" alt = "" width = "250px" height ="300px"/>'; ?>
to fetch the image. but on clicking the product in the product  page it always opens the first image's description.

Comment: It is. However, I have to have the Productsdetails.php page working to check if the session is active.